# Extract 2d ndarray from arbitrarily dimensional ndarray using index arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to extract parts of an numpy ndarray based on arrays of index positions for some of the dimensions. Let me show this on an example

## Example data

```
dummy = np.random.rand(5,2,100)
X = np.array([[0,1],[4,1],[2,0]])
```

`dummy` is the original ndarray with dimensionality 5x2x100. This dimensionality is arbitrary, it could as well be 5x2x4x100.
`X` is a matrix of index values, here `X[:,0]` are the indices of the first dimension of `dummy`, `X[:,1]` those of the second dimension. The number of columns in X is always the number of dimensions in `dummy` minus 1.

## Example output

I want to extract an ndarray of the following form for this example

```
[
  dummy[0,1,:],
  dummy[4,1,:],
  dummy[2,0,:]
]
```

## Complications

If the number of dimensions in `dummy` were fixed, this could just be done by `dummy[X[:,0],X[:,1],:]` . Sadly the dimensionality can be different, e.g. `dummy` could be a 5x2x4x6x100 ndarray and `X` correspondingly would then be 3x4 . My attempts at dealing with it have not yielded the desired result.

- `dummy[X,:]` yields a 3x2x2x100 ndarray for this example same as `dummy[X]`
- Iteratively reducing `dummy` by doing something like `dummy = dummy[X[:,i],:]` with `i` an iterator over the number of columns of `X` also does not reduce the ndarray in the example past 3x2x100

I have a feeling that this should be pretty simple with numpy indexing, but I guess my search for a solution was missing the right terms for this.
Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: `dummy[(*X.T,)]` ?

Comment: Thank you, that works. Although I don't quite understand it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to provide some explainability to @Michael Szczesny answer.

First, notice that if you have an `np.array` with dimension `n` and pass  `m` indexes where `m<n`, then it will be the same as using `:` in the dimensions `>=m`. In your case, for example:

```
dummy[(0, 0)] == dummy[0, 0, :]
```

Given that, note that you can also pass an array as an index. Thus:

```
dummy[([0, 1], [0, 0])]
```

It would be the same as:

```
np.array([dummy[(0,0)], dummy[(1,0)]])
```

You can validate that using:

```
dummy[([0, 1], [0, 0])] == np.array([dummy[(0,0)], dummy[(1,0)]])
```

Finally, notice that:

```
(*X.T,)
# (array([0, 4, 2]), array([1, 1, 0]))
```

You are here getting each dimension as an array, and then you will get:

```
[
  dummy[0,1],
  dummy[4,1],
  dummy[2,0]
]
```

Which is the same as:

```
[
  dummy[0,1,:],
  dummy[4,1,:],
  dummy[2,0,:]
]
```

Edit: Instead of using (*X.T,), you can use tuple(X.T), which for me, makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

as Michael Szczesny wrote, the best solution is `dummy[(*X.T,)]`.

Since `X[:,0]` are the indices of the first dimension of `dummy` and `X[:,1]` are the indices of the second dimension of `dummy`, if you transpose `X` (`X.T`) you'll have the the indices of the first dimension of `dummy` as `X.T[0]` and the indices of the second dimension of `dummy` as `X.T[1]`.

Now to slice `dummy` as you want, you can specify the indices of the first and of the second dimension in this way:

```
dummy[(first_dim_indices, second_dim_indices)] = dummy[(X.T[0], X.T[1])]
```

In order to simplify the code (and since you doesn't want to transpose the `X` matrix twice) you can unpack `X.T` in a tuple as `(*X.T,)` and so write `X[(*X.T,)]` is the same thing to write `dummy[(X.T[0], X.T[1])]`.

This writing is also useful if you have an unfixed number of dimensions to slice trough because you will unpack from `X.T` as many lines as there are dimensions to slice in `dummy`. For example suppose you want to retrieve an 1D-array from `dummy` given the following indices:

```
first_dim:  (0, 4, 2)
second_dim: (1, 1, 0)
third_dim:  (9, 8, 7)
```

You can specify the indices of the 3 dimensions as `X = np.array([[0,1,9],[4,1,8],[2,0,7]])` and `dim[(*X.T,)]` is still valid.